# Telerik MVC extensions and culture problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik components for ASP.NET MVC 3. Problem is extension method output differ for current culture. For example if i use en-Us for current culture and everything works ok but if i changed it to tr-TR then some of editor components doesn't work as expected. For example t-insertImage class on div is changing to t-ınsertImage.

```
//i am changing culture like this.
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
```

Then simply using

```
@Html.Telerik().Editor().Name("editor")
```

And now some of editor tools doesnt work. Try insert image.

I tried to Globalization and Encode methods parameters to true and false but still same problem.

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess we didn't pass the [Turkey test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) :)

Thanks for the heads up, we're currently working on the issue and will provide a fix in the next internal build. You can fix it in your version of the source by patching the `ToCamelCase` method in **StringExtensions.cs** to use `ToLowerInvariant`, like so:

```
public static string ToCamelCase(this string instance)
{
    Guard.IsNotNullOrEmpty(instance, "instance");

    return instance[0].ToString().ToLowerInvariant() + instance.Substring(1);
}
```